# PHP Session can work without cookies?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I read lot of articles and found session can not work without cookie but tried and found a way please provide feedback on this ?

step 1) first disable and clear cookie data of browser i am using chrome.

step 2) create a page one.php that have following code.
i have firstly detect user agent that ipaddress and my secret key convert it into MD5 same on second page for unique user detection.

```
$uagent = base64_encode($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
echo $ip = md5($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."MYSECRETKEY".$uagent);
echo "<br>";
echo session_id($ip);
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = array("name"=>"bbbbbbbb","designation"=>"software_engineer");
print_r($_SESSION);
```

step3) create another page two.php

```
$uagent = base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
echo $ip = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."MYSECRETKEY".$uagent);
echo "<br>";
echo session_id($ip);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I found data on two.php page.so we can set session and grab data without cookie.
Any feedback i am wrong or this is really a solution?

Comment: IP's can be faked.  If they have a dynamic IP a modem reset could lose their session.  Multiple users could be on the same IP, like in an office building or a college campus.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't take into account multiple users from the same IP address, such as those who are using the same household router, or different users on the same machine etc. You CAN use sessions without cookies if you append the session id to the url (e.g. `two.php?sessionid=sdfgsdfgasdfsdgsdfgsdfgsdfg`)

Comment: but it will work like digital signature this is secure using MD5 or any encryption algo. i know this will not work on network like offices where uses same IP's  otherwise MD5 can't readable or anything we append with the string.

Answer (score 0):

This would work as long as the user agent and the remote address are the same. But you can just hijack into a session if you know

- someone's public IP
- someone's user agent

The visitor submits this data to each site he visits, and cannot prevent that! A hijacking is a very simple task, if the visitor have visited a bad site before, which saved the data.

> This is not really a secure solution! Do not use it!

EDIT: Ok, you have to spoof the IP address which is a bit complicate :-) But in public networks, the problem persists, there can be even collisions.

Comment: but we have a unique secret key , hijacking is issue but session hijacking also possible.

Comment: Yes, but the risk is higher. You just have to spoof IP address (not so easy but possible) and user agent. No random ID -> insecure!